# implementation of push-relabel algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, max-flow, push-relabel

I was learning the push-relabel algorithm from the topcoder site: http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=maxflowPushRelabel
 I think there is something wrong with the implementation. How can a node push back the excess flow to the node when it is saturated. For instance:

[image]

While finding the max flow from 1 to 3, at one stage I'll need to push back the flow from 2 to 1(since 2 has no outgoing edges). But in the code implementation of the First-in First-out algorithm, the loop at line number **16** runs from `0 to G[u].size()`.  Since 2 doesn't have any edge from 2 to 1, how can it push the flow back to 1?

Here is my crappy implementation if required:

```
#define DEBUG       //comment when you have to disable all debug macros.
#define LOCAL
#define NDEBUG    //comment when all assert statements have to be disabled.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <utility> //std::pair
#include <cassert>
#define tr(c,i) for(typeof(c.begin()) i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++) 
#define present(c,x) ((c).find(x) != (c).end()) 
#define all(x) x.begin(), x.end()
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
#define log2(x) (log(x)/log(2))
#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) (1[&arr]-arr)      
#define INDEX(arr,elem)        (lower_bound(all(arr),elem)-arr.begin())
#define lld long long int
#define MOD 1000000007
#define gcd __gcd
#define equals(a,b) (a.compare(b)==0)    //for strings only
using namespace std;



struct Graph{
   lld numV;
   vector<lld> *adj;
   lld **flow, **cap, **cf, *height, *excess;
      inline void SET0(lld *array)
      {
         for(lld i=0;i<=numV;i++)
            array[i]=0;
      }
   Graph(lld _numV)
      {
         numV=_numV;
         lld i;
         /* allocating memory....*/
         flow = new lld*[numV+1];
         for(i=0;i<=numV;i++)
            flow[i] = new lld[numV+1], SET0(flow[i]);
         cap = new lld*[numV+1];
         for(i=0;i<=numV;i++)
            cap[i] = new lld[numV+1], SET0(cap[i]);
         cf = new lld*[numV+1];
         for(i=0;i<=numV;i++)
            cf[i] = new lld[numV+1], SET0(cf[i]);

         height = new lld[numV+1];
         excess = new lld[numV+1];
         SET0(height);
         SET0(excess);
         adj = new vector<lld>[numV+1];
      }
   void addEdge(lld u, lld v, lld uv)
      {
         adj[u].push_back(v);
         cap[u][v] = uv;
         cf[u][v] = uv;
      }

   void initialize_preflow(lld source)
      {
         lld i, v;
         height[source] = numV-1;

         tr(adj[source],it)
         {
            v = *it;
            flow[source][v] = cap[source][v];
            flow[v][source] = -cap[source][v];
            excess[v] += cap[source][v];
            excess[source] -=cap[source][v];
            cf[source][v] = cap[source][v]-flow[source][v];
            cf[v][source] = cap[v][source]-flow[v][source];
         }
      }
   void push(lld u, lld v)
      {
         lld push_val = min(cf[u][v], excess[u]);
         flow[u][v] += push_val;
         flow[v][u] = -flow[u][v];
         excess[u] -=push_val;
         excess[v] +=push_val;
         cf[u][v] = cap[u][v]-flow[u][v];
         cf[v][u] = cap[v][u]-flow[v][u];
      }
   lld max_flow(lld source, lld sink)
      {
         initialize_preflow(source);
         queue<lld> q;
         bool considered[numV+1];
         lld u, v, m, i;
         memset(considered, false, sizeof(considered));
         tr(adj[source], it)
         {
            v = *it;
            if(v!=sink)
            {
               q.push(v);
               considered[v] = true;
            }
         }
         bool flag;
         u = -1;
         while(!q.empty())
         {

            u = q.front();
            m = -1;
            for(i=0;i<adj[u].size() && excess[u]>0; i++)
            {

               v = adj[u][i];
               if(cf[u][v]>0)
               {
                  if(height[u]>height[v])
                  {
                     push(u,v);
                     if(!considered[v] && v!=sink && v!=source)
                     {
                        considered[v] = true;
                        q.push(v);
                     }
                  }
                  else if(m==-1) m = height[v];
                  else   m = min(m, height[v]);
               }
            }

            if(adj[u].empty()) {q.pop();continue;}
            if(excess[u]!=0) height[u] = m+1;
            else
            {
               q.pop();
               considered[u] = false;
            }
         }
         return excess[sink];
      }

};

template<class T>
inline void inputInt(T &n )
{
   n=0;
   T ch=getchar_unlocked();
     while( ch < '0' || ch > '9' )
      ch=getchar_unlocked();
      while(  ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' )
       n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0', ch=getchar_unlocked();
}

int main()
{
#ifdef LOCAL
   freopen("input.in","r",stdin);
#endif
   lld e,u,v,n,c;
   //cout<<"V:"<<endl;
   cin>>n>>e;

   Graph g(n);
   while(e--)
   {

      inputInt(u);
      inputInt(v);
      inputInt(c);
      if(u!=v)
      {
         if(g.cf[u][v])
            g.cf[u][v]=g.cf[v][u]=g.cap[u][v]=g.cap[v][u]+c;
         else g.addEdge(u,v,c);
      }
   }
   cout<<g.max_flow(1,n)<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Holy wall of `#include`s, Batman!

Comment: Methinks you `#define` too much.

Comment: Sorry for that...I usually have a default list of preprocessors.

Answer (score 1):

I just reimplemented the push-relabel algorithm from topcoder. And I exactly faced the same problem. It is some kind of bad described at the turorial. But the solution is, that you add an edge to your graph in the opposite direction of your directed graph - each edge with capacity 0!

E.g. add edge(3,1) and edge(2,1) to your example graph above, both with capacity 0.

If you have a undirected graph, this question is unnecessary of course, as you add two identical edges (u,v) and (v,u) to your graph with the same capacity.

I hope I could help  if not, just ask :)